# NodeJS Child Process when calling Java keytool command on Windows

Tags: java, node.js, keytool

I m trying to run this code  on Windows machine. I want to use Java Keytool in my node.js application.

```
var KEYTOOL_COMMAND="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_31     \\bin\\keytool";
   var ktArgs = ["-genkey", "-v", "-keystore", "test1.keystore", "-alias", "test", "-keyalg", "RSA", "-keysize" ,"2048", "-validity", "10000"];

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var cmd = spawn(KEYTOOL_COMMAND, ktArgs);
  cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

 cmd.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
 cmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {

   cmd.stdin.write("password\n");
 });

    cmd.on('close', function (code) {
   console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
   });
```

But code give me this error. What's wrong in code?

```
      C:\Users\nazır\Desktop\keytool>node index.js
    stdout: keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many retries, program terminated

   stdout: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many retries, program terminated
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.getX500Name(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doGenKeyPair(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)

   child process exited with code 1
```

Comment: did you found any solution for this?